# Reading docker-compose environment variables in application code

Tags: docker-compose

Maybe I'm being *really* dumb and not understanding it properly; I want to define my `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```
web:
  ...
  environment:
    FOO: bar
    BAR: foo
```

And I want to expose those environment variables for my runtime applications that will run inside the container (I guess by mapping them to shell variables?).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: That is what happens by default

Comment: Does it? It doesn't seem to happen for me. For example when I launch a container and try to echo an environment variable in, say, the bash shell, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: What's the entrypoint into the app? Is it the bash shell?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a minor syntax issue in your yml, try changing it to:

```
web:
  ...
  environment:
    - FOO=bar
    - BAR=foo
```

You should then be able to access those variables in your code as expected.